# how can i get object data from array by using filter or find?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

i have a two data. one is array and the other is object like this

I want to put the value that matches the ReplyCommentId value of the replycomment object and the id value of the ReplyComments array as an object in selectreplycomment.

```
            replycomment: 
            {
            CommentId: 67
            PostId: 2
            ReplyCommentId: 32
            User: {id: 3, nickname: "스티브잡스"}
            UserId: 3
            active: "1"
            content: "11"
            createdAt: "2021-03-14T11:27:57.000Z"
            id: 96
            updatedAt: "2021-03-15T07:35:20.000Z"
            }
```

how can i do that?

```
            ReplyComments : [

            0: {id: 30, CommentId: 66}
            1: {id: 32, CommentId: 67}
            2: {id: 33, CommentId: 78}
            3: {id: 34, CommentId: 78}
            4: {id: 35, CommentId: null}
            5: {id: 36, CommentId: null}
            6: {id: 37, CommentId: null}
            7: {id: 43, CommentId: 66}
                            ]
```

expected value

```
            selectreplycomment :

            { CommentId: 67
            PostId: 2
            ReplyCommentId: 32
            User: {id: 3, nickname: "스티브잡스"}
            UserId: 3
            active: "1"
            content: "11"
            createdAt: "2021-03-14T11:27:57.000Z"
            id: 96
            updatedAt: "2021-03-15T07:35:20.000Z" }
```

Comment: your questions is a bit confusing but try using [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) if you are willing to find an object (the first one that match the predicate) data in an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `filter` function and search for the same `CommentId`.

```js
const replycomment = {
  CommentId: 67,
  PostId: 2,
  ReplyCommentId: 32,
  User: {id: 3, nickname: "스티브잡스"},
  UserId: 3,
  active: "1",
  content: "11",
  createdAt: "2021-03-14T11:27:57.000Z",
  id: 96,
  updatedAt: "2021-03-15T07:35:20.000Z",
}; 
            
const ReplyComments = [
  {id: 30, CommentId: 66},
  {id: 32, CommentId: 67},
  {id: 33, CommentId: 78},
  {id: 34, CommentId: 78},
  {id: 35, CommentId: null},
  {id: 36, CommentId: null},
  {id: 37, CommentId: null},
  {id: 43, CommentId: 66},
];                          
const res = ReplyComments.filter((e) => e.CommentId == replycomment.CommentId);
console.log('res', res);
```